# Having issue showing data to html table using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is when i click the button to show the data from database to html table it shows up but when i try to click the button again it duplicates the content of the table and it continues to duplicate as long as i click the button.

`script:`

```
$('#showData').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Oppa/view/file.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {tag: 'getData', code: $('#emailCodeResult').val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $.each(data, function(index, record) {
                    if ($.isNumeric(index)) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        row.appendTo("#myTable2 tbody");
                    }
                })
            }
            $('#myTable2').dataTable({
                "bjQueryUI": true,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bAutoWidth": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bLengthChange": false
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What would you like it to do, refresh the data?

Comment: Remove the rows at each update, otherwise you keep appending

Comment: you should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670579/how-to-replace-and-append-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$("#myTable2 tbody").empty()` to remove the rows before appending:

```
success: function(data){
        if(data.success){
            $("#myTable2 tbody").empty(); //<------------------------------------
            $.each(data, function(index, record){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#myTable2 tbody').empty();` before fetching your JSON Array. This will remove existing rows of your Table before adding new ones. The Table Header will remain though.

EDIT:

Changed from .remove() to .empty() based on comment below

Comment: $('#myTable2 tbody').empty();

Comment: Only difference is that $('#myTable2 tbody').remove(); removes the tbody tag as well :)